# Get results from third-party API and dump the results in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and cloud services in general. What I plan to do is to continuously get data from a third party API which returns results in JSON at a time (3-5 MB each) and dump the results into a S3 bucket. I want to automate the process and my solution for the moment is to run a python script on an EC2 instance to get results and transfer to the S3 bucket as I would manually do on local. Is that the way to achieve such data collection? As I'm new to this, I want to stay within the free tier. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a typical size of the response from API. As far as I understand, it's an experimental project. I hope these tips will help:

- Have a look at [aws free tier page](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=categories%2312monthsfree&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=productcategories%23storage)
- Use t2.micro
- Set up billing alerts on aws - anything can happen, paying $5 is still better than paying $500.

I'm not sure if you already use s3, but these are also some things to consider:

- Calculate how much data you will be storing in MB
- Set up lifecycle policy on s3 to delete objects that are N days old (unless you need them).
- Make sure versioning is off (unless you need it)

*From docs: Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 5 GB of Amazon S3 storage in the **Standard** Storage class, 20,000 Get Requests, **2,000 Put Requests**, and 15 GB of data transfer out **each month** for one year*

So, you probably want to put objects to s3 in batches (I mean one object will contain several responses from API). If the script will run every second and push objects to s3, looks like 2000 free put requests are the bottleneck.

[prices for s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Right now I get what I wanted to do by running a python script on an ec2 instance in background (nohup). However, this requires the instance running (and consuming quota) continuously while I only do a data dump every few hours. I am looking at a solution using AWS Lambda that does not require the instance running all the time.